# how to force page not to load from cache if there are changes in page

Tags: html, http-headers, meta-tags, browser-cache

I have a site with advertisements and so the user is able to change his advertisement. But if the user goes to his own advertisement the page is the same, because the page loads from the browser cache. I can use a meta tag that tels the page not to cache and Always load from the server, but is there a way to check for updates (date changed in database) on the server and if there are no updates load the page from cache?